# How to reset an user password without knowing his current password?

Tags: passwd

A colleague has just resigned. And his account is being used as a build account on our **Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS**.

Is there any way to reset his password without knowing his current password? I have tried `sudo passwd $HIS_USER` but it asks for current his current password (not mine).

And

- The Ubuntu is using LDAP authentication
- I can't reboot the server into GRUB because I'm working remotely

Comment: Check your system is 16.04.6, as that would imply you're behind on security patches and fixes, as a fully *upgraded* system should report itself as 16.04.7 (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-16-04-7-lts-released/ where the date shows the ISO release date, installed systems upgraded to it before that date)

Comment: `sudo passwd $HIS_USER` should ask for your password to authenticate to `sudo`, and shouldn't ask for `$HIS_USER`'s password (unless you're using LDAP or something like that).

Comment: His account is a ldap. I can try above command for a local user, but not him.

Comment: LDAP server -> server admin?

Comment: You should be able to manipulate the /etc/sudoers file so that you can sudo into this user without being prompted for a password, and fully impersonate him to the system. Of course, if the user account is disabled in LDAP, you may run into issues with the other information (UID, GID, home directory) isn't available from LDAP, either.

Answer (score 3):

login as root or type sudo su. Then you can set a new password for user with `passwd [user]`.

Furthermore you could copy any other encrypted password from /etc/shadow to this user.

Comment: His account is a ldap. There is no /etc/shadow for him.

Comment: Then you have to deal with ldap admin.

Comment: There is an almost-complete workaround to that situation. Create a new local user with a different user name, but the same UID (you will need the -o argument to useradd) and the same home directory. You can then log on with that local user name as if you were that user. There is one difference that could possibly trip up a script: the user name will not be set correctly.